# How to use https in Amazon EC2 with NGINX and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

After 12 hours, I could not make HTTPS work in my application.
I did:

1. In **Amazon Certificate Manager**, I created a certificate for my domain;
2. In **Security Groups** - Inbound Tab, I included the HTTPS (HTTPS -
   TCP - 443 - 0.0.0.0/0)
3. I created a **Classic Load Balancer** and included 2 listners:

   - HTTP - Port 80
   - HTTPS - Port 443 | Instance Protocol HTTP | INSTANCE PORT 80 | Associate my certificate (step 1 - ACM Amazon Certificate Manger)
4. In **Amazon Route 53** - Hosted Zones, I added 2 records in my hosted zone:

   - CNAME www with value mydomain.com
   - Type A IPv4 Address | Alias YES | Alias Target: My Load Balancer

In tutorials I saw (youtube + internet), only with the steps above the HTTPS works on Amazon EC2. But, the tutorials is not for NGINX and Ruby On Rails.

The error I get is: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

After more search:

5. Using ssh, I went to: /etc/nginx/sites-available/*myapp* and I removed the comment: **listen 443 ssl;**

After restart nginx, I got 2 random errors: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSE

I don't know more what to do.

Some prints:

**Security Group**
[image: Security Group]

**Load Balancer - Tab Instances**
[image: Load Balancer - Tab Instances]

**Load Balancer - Tab Listners**
[image: Load Balancer - Tab Listners]

**Amazon Hosted Zones**
[image: Amazon Hosted Zones]

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp**
[image: /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp]

**My Environment**

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: Rails 4.2.3
nginx -v: nginx/1.8.0
```

Tks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the domain's DNS records did not point to my EC2.
When I registered the custom domain, I leaved the DNS records default.
In domain advanced DNS zone, I pointed "*.domain.com" and "@.domain.com" to my EC2 public IP. But it not works when we use a Load Balancer.

Then, I went to my domain panel, I changed the DNS, pointing to my EC2.
Are 4 DNS, like this:

```
ns-XXX.awsdns-XXX.org
ns-XXX.awsdns-XXX.co.uk
ns-XXX.awsdns-XXX.net
ns-XXX.awsdns-XXX.com
```

After the DNS propagation, the Amazon Route 53 will be the responsible to manage the server DNS records.

In Amazon Route 53 (Amazon Hosted Zones), I have an alias record, that use my Load Balancer.

If you want to use an Amazon Certificate Manger (ACM), follow the steps 1 to 4 in my question. And remember, point your domain DNS to Amazon EC2.
Forget the step 5.

I followed a [tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5MYky95atE) to do this to work.
If you alredy have an instance (like me), ignore the create instance process. I ignored the Elastic IP create process too.

And now, https works fine.